# After UK visitor visa refusal, can I get a Schengen tourist visa

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, visa-refusals, schengen-visas

I have been refused twice for UK visitor visa. Can I apply for Schengen visa easily for holiday tour. Will my UK refusal impact my Schengen application. I am from India, New Delhi.

Comment: What were the refusal reasons? Do you have any prior travel history?

Comment: No , i m first timer, i m single, doing job in india. Stay with old mother. They dont see personal ties, how should i prove my ties despite having job and old age mother staying with me here

Comment: @kaurkaur If you’ve never travelled outside India, first focus on building up a travel history to countries that allow Indian citizens visa-free/evisa entry. It’s highly unlikely you’ll get a visitor visa for any of Schengen/UK/Canada/USA without a good prior travel history. https://visaguide.world/visa-free-countries/indian-passport/

Comment: But despite having gud job, gud funds, why they refuse just on basis of strong ties, as i mentioned i m living with old age mother and i will surely come back

Comment: They don’t know that you will ‘surely come back’ because a) many people in your situation do not, they overstay and find a way to support family back home; and b) you haven’t got a record of showing that you go back after having travelled outside India.

Comment: @kaurkaur, keep in mind that it is definitely not impossible for Indians to get a Schengen visa. Hundreds of thousands get it. But with two UK rejections, it may be better to wait until you have a better job and more ties to India. You should not reveal too many details on the web, so we cannot know if your finances are stable enough.

Answer (score 5):

Both the UK and the EU want visitors who come and spend money or arrange business. They do not want irregular immigration by people who pretend to be tourists and then overstay or claim asylum.

The UK and the Schengen area have **separate systems**, but they use **similar criteria**. If you did not meet the criteria for an UK visa twice, it may be difficult to meet the criteria for a Schengen visa. Both will want to see stable ties to your place of residence. Both will want to see a financial situation which makes tourism plausible.

But there may be conditions which make an UK visit more difficult than a Schengen visit, like family ties to the UK. So go back to your UK refusals. If there were specific concerns in there, you may have a chance in the EU. If it was something generic like V 4.2 a+c, the Schengen officers will have the same concerns.

Comment: Although i showed proof tat i m employed in india and will surely come back, then also they refuse on personal ties to country

Comment: @kaurkaur, you cannot *prove* that you will *surely* come back. They would look how your current salary in India would compare to what you could earn in the UK, and also how stable your job is.

Comment: @kaurkaur They will also look at your history of *going back*. If you don’t have one, it’s far more likely you’ll be refused *even if everything else stacks up*. Having employment isn’t necessarily strong proof of ties either, it may depend on the type of job eg if the job can be done remotely, as is increasingly the case.